# Why Element script cannot nested inside element ul error occurs

Tags: javascript, html, visual-studio, razor

View contains `ul` list. `li` elements in this list contains `<a>` element. Clicking in a element should invoke javascript method which is defined immediately after every li element:

```
<ul>
<li><a href="#" onclick="Method2()">Method1</a></li>
<script>
function Method1() {
  ... javascript code for Method1
}
</script>

<li><a href="#" onclick="Method2()">Method2</a></li>
<script>
function Method2() {
  ... javascript code for method1
}
</script>
... other similar links
</ul>
```

Microsoft Visual Studio Express 2013 Razor view editor is used to create razor view having this code.

It throws

```
Element 'script' cannot nested inside element 'ul' error.
```

[image]

Application runs without issues.
Why this error occurs ?
Is it safe to ignore it ?
Which is best practice for this ? Javascript contains lot of parameters from Model so it is difficult to move it into separate js file.

Comment: If you ask about better practices, you must have external js file for your javascript code. At worst case you can have it at the bottom of the page just before closing of body tag. Nested script tags ??? Not a way to go !

Comment: Question describes that javascript code contains lot of data injected from ViewModel. To put them into separate file requires huge code refactoring. Not sure is this reasonable, So I asked is it OK to keep current code and ignore error.

Comment: its safe to ignore, just perhaps bad mark up.

Comment: Will every browser run code from `<script>` elements nested in `<ul>` ?

Comment: i cant answer for all definitively, but yes, google & co will.

Comment: This has "code smell" to me here. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_smell